# transformation - True or False?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

The function $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T\pmatrix{\mathbb{x}_1, \mathbb{x}_2} = x_1 - x_2$ is linear?

I think it is false, but not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Check the definition of linearity.

Is $T(a x_1, a x_2)=a T(x_1,x_2)$?

Is $T(x_1,x_2)+T(y_1,y_2)=T(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$?

Comment: this makes me think it is true...

Comment: That's because it is

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer says, you can check the definition. This would be very easy to do.

Let me point out something else.  A function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation exactly when there exists an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $T(x) = Ax$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that your function 
$$
T\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2} = x_1 - x_2 = \pmatrix{1 & -1}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2}.
$$
From this you see that $T$ is actually given by multiplication by the $1\times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{1 & -1}$. So it is a linear transformation.

Again, I think it would be easiest for you to just check the definition, but my answer might help you identify linear transformations faster.

Comment: so I guess it is true?

Comment: @Anonymous: Yep.